# How can I get a character at a given index in Perl?

Tags: perl, string

If I have a Perl string:

```
$str = "Hello";
```

how can I get a character at a given index similar to charAt(index)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `substr` with length 1 as in:

```
$nth = substr($string, n-1, 1);
```

Also lookup [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=4688) for other solutions.

Answer (score 24):

```
$char = substr( $mainstring, $i , 1 );
```

Is one way to do it, probably the clearest.

If what you were wanting was the *numeric* value and you were intending to do this lots:

```
unpack("W*","hello")
```

Returns an array of Char values:

```
print join ",", unpack("W*","hello")  ; 
#  104,101,108,108,111
```

For proper Unicode/Utf8 stuff you might want to use

```
use utf8;
unpack("U*","hello\0ƀ\n") 
# 104,101,108,108,111,0,384,10
```

Comment: Or just `ord(substr($mainstring, $i, 1))`

Comment: The thing is, usually when you want the value of one character, you want the value of all of them, and looping through ord(substr()) is going to be both less efficient, and harder to read, and harder to debug, than the unpack variant.

Answer (score 4):

Corollary to the other substr() answers is that you can use it to *set* values at an index also.  It supports this as lvalue or with extra arguments.  It's also very similar to splice, which is the same thing, but for arrays.

```
$string = "hello";
substr($string, 2, 2) = "this works?";
substr($string, 2, 2, "same thing basically");
@a = qw(s t r i n g s a n d t h i n g s);
@cut_out = splice(@a, 2, 2);
@cut_out = splice(@a, 2, 2, @replacement);
```

Comment: Somebody Should point out the `substr( x, y, z ) = foo`  is equivalent to `substr( x, y, z, foo )`, but the latter notation is recommended as the former is frequently confusing to newbies.

Comment: You just did!  I think I also did in the phrase "same thing basically."  I would assume that a newb looking at this example would fire up the pod page for substr and notice the LVALUE magic and use the four argument form since the LVALUE form is weird and scary — and it says so on the pod.  Perhaps I have too much faith in the newbs?

Answer (score 0):

To get a character at the ith index, use `substr`. To fetch the 2nd index character, for example:

```
$str="Perl";
print substr($str,2,1).
```

This will give the output `r`.

Comment: Sorry, 
the code will be substr($str,2,1);
So, basically for getting nth character in a string, the format will be substr(string,index,1). I hope this helps.

Comment: It certainly helps. but what does your answer bring that the other answers above posted 10 years before yours don't?